# Error setting up Mercurial on Windows Server 2008

Tags: python, mercurial, windows-server-2008

I want to set up a Mercurial SC server and have been following the instructions found here: http//stackoverflow.com/questions/818571/how-to-setup-mercurial-and-hgwebdir-on-iis

I have checked all my settings multiple times and cannot seem to get passed this error after completing the configuration.  *Any advice would be helpful.  Thank you.*

```
Server Error in Application "DEFAULT WEB SITE/HG"Internet Information Services 7.5

Error Summary
HTTP Error 502.2 - Bad Gateway
The specified CGI application misbehaved by not returning a complete set of HTTP headers. The headers it did return are "Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\inetpub\hgcgi\hgwebdir.cgi", line 12, in <module> from mercurial import demandimport; demandimport.enable() ImportError: No module named mercurial ". Detailed Error InformationModule CgiModule
Notification ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler Python 2.5
**Error Code 0x00000001**
Requested URL http://localhost:80/hg/hgwebdir.cgi
Physical Path C:\inetpub\hgcgi\hgwebdir.cgi
Logon Method Anonymous
Logon User Anonymous
 Most likely causes:
The CGI process was shut down or terminated unexpectedly before it finished processing the request.
The CGI process has a flaw and does not return a complete set of HTTP headers.
 Things you can try:
Check the event logs on the system to see whether the CGI process is shutting down unexpectedly.
Troubleshoot the CGI application to determine why it is not sending a complete set of HTTP headers.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The traceback in the very long line says that mercurial isn't found in your PYTHON_PATH.  Try making the hgwebdir.cgi edit as seen in step 5.1 from the [HgWebDirStopByStep](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HgWebDirStepByStep#Mercurial_Lib_Files) page.

```
# adjust python path if not a system-wide install:
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "c:/dev/Mercurial/lib")
```

Where, of course, the path element that's being inserted is adjusted to reference wherever your mercurial library files are.

Comment: I have mercurail 1.4.2 installed and can run it from my command line.  I have the cgi and the virtual directory registered in IIS and followed directions thoroughly...any other suggestions?

Comment: I adjusted the answer to include explicitly adding the path to the mercurial library files to the .cgi.