# Unable to get Mercurial's hgweb.cgi working on IIS7

Tags: python, iis, mercurial, sql-server-2008-r2, hgweb

I have been using this guide http://tinyurl.com/mercurial-iis to attempt to setup Mercurial on IIS 7.  I have followed every step however when I try to access the site I get the following error:

> **Error Summary**
>
> HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
> There is a
> problem with the resource you are
> looking for, so it cannot be
> displayed.
>
> **Detailed Error Information**
>
> Module **IsapiModule**
> Notification **ExecuteRequestHandler**
> Handler **Mercurial-ISAPI**
> Error Code **0x8007007e**
>
> Requested URL **http://localhost:81/**
> Physical Path **C:\inetpub\hg**
> Logon Method **Anonymous**
> Logon User **Anonymous**

I am using the following setup:

- Windows Server 2008 SP2 x64 OS
- IIS7
- Python 2.6.6 32bit
- Mercurial 1.7.5 32bit
- pywin32-215

Comment: If you get that 500 server error in Internet Explorer, try visiting the options page, advanced options, and then find and disable "Show Friendly HTTP Error Messages", see if it then shows more useful information when it crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.7.1+ changed a few things that aren't reflected in most of the links floating around.  Try [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355256/mercurial-and-hgweb-on-iis-7-5-python-error/4367589#4367589) that I posted a while back, it seems like a few people have been successful with it.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend dropping the ISAPI and try going down the CGI route. That's what we did - and it has been working flawlessly. It's not like the performance difference is going to be noticeable anyway.

Useful links:

- http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/mercurial-on-iis7/  (we followed this guide almost religiously)
- http://vampirebasic.blogspot.com/2009/06/running-mercurial-on-windows.html
- http://www.endswithsaurus.com/2010/05/setting-up-and-configuring-mercurial-in.html
- [How to setup Mercurial and hgwebdir on IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818571/how-to-setup-mercurial-and-hgwebdir-on-iis/886986#886986)

Comment: It was my understanding that the CGI route does not work for Mercurial 1.7.5 on IIS and that using the ISAPI dll is now the method.

Comment: I don't think the CGI method will ever stop working. It's pretty much a fail safe method...